# Help with understanding the contour integrals in Laurent series.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

i have been reading about Laurent series. Their formal definition is given as

$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {b_n} {(z-a)^n} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n  $$

Where  $ b_n = \frac { 1}{2i\pi}\int_\Gamma f(w)(w-a)^{n-1} dw $

and    $ a_n =\frac {1}{2i\pi}\int_\Gamma \frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{n+1}} dw $

Pretty much everywhere i read about this ALL examples just use manipulations of geometric series to find the Laurent expansion. However i was looking to see if anyone could educate me specifically on which contour is used, if i were to decide to use contour integration to find the $a_n$ and $b_n$ coefficients.

Lets say for example finding the series expansion of  $ \frac {1}{1-z} $ valid for $ |z|  > 1 $ which is $$  - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^n} $$ but using contour integration please.

I apologize if this is not worded properly. Thank you very much in advance for your help educating me and your time.

Comment: I think you can find a good explanation of the contour at the wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series

Comment: Look at the Wikipedia page. "The path of integration $\Gamma$ is counterclockwise around a Jordan curve enclosing c and lying in an annulus A in which $f(z)$ is holomorphic(analytic)". I believe we can actually go more general than Jordan Curves in theory, but that's practically what you need.